# How to solve function for x having x and x^2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the following funktion for $x$, is that possible? And how woult it look like?

$y = xp -qx^{2}$

Thanks for Help!

Comment: use the quadratic formula

Comment: This is not an equation, this is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we have $$y=xp-x^2q$$

The above equation can be solved for $x$ in terms of $p$ & $y$. The above equation can be rearranged as follows $$q\color{red}{x^2}-p\color{red}{x}+y=0$$ The above equation is a quadratic equation of form $\color{blue}{Ax^2+Bx+C=0}$ in terms of variable $x$ which can be solved by using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the multiplications then add $qx^2-px$ to both sides of the equation to get

$$qx^2-px+y=0$$

This is now a quadratic equation in standard from $ax^2+bx+c=0$, with $a=q,b=-p,c=y$. Substitute those values into the quadratic formula to get your solution(s) to the equation. I'll leave that last part to you.